# Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics DLR memory leak?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, windbg

I'm facing an issue with a large amount of  objects under the Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics namespace showing up on the heap.

We've speculated that this has something to do with the following piece of code:

```
if (m_DictionaryXXX.TryGetValue(participant.Id, out callback))
{
  //Some implementation using callback
}
```

TryGetValue is now treated as a dynamic expression.
When debugging, we've noticed the thread calling TryGetValue hangs on the TryGetValue call.

It is important to note four things.

- m_DictionaryXXX is a ConcurrentDictionary.
- participant is a dynamic object, returned from an IEnumerable.
- The dynamic object in itself is instantiated as an anonymous type.
- On all dumps tested, GC heap size varies from 800-1100MB

Because of the body limitation on stackoverflow, please refer to the codetidy link below for more data, and 
windbg output.

http://codetidy.com/7622/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm facing similar problem, do you have any solution to that problem?

Comment: Hi, we were waiting for a concrete response from microsoft on the issue. I suggest changing the anonymous type to a concrete type for fast resolution.

Comment: Can't do that... the idea of my software is that it's dynamic. I replaced buggy ExpandoObject class (minimum functionality) and as for now it's fine. I'm only facing old Linq memory leaks now.